# Xcode unit test fail runnings immediately (without)

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xctestcase

My project's unit test fails even before running!:
[image]

I've cleaned the build director, restarted simulator, tried on the device, disabled code signing, restarted Xcode...everything!

I <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>, and it fails immediately.
I use CocoaPods, so run it in a workspace.

Comment: What does it say in the console log? (…Without giving away your login or project name)

Comment: too little information to help you. share the debug navigator logs

Comment: @JonReid, staticVoidMan Sorry guys, there was nothing displayed in the logs. But it was fixed after restarting the computer. Thanks for offering to help guys!

Answer (score 0):

It works now, after restarting the computer!
Weird.